# The named parameter 'default' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I Got This Weird Error:

"The named parameter 'default' isn't defined.Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'default'."

I think error in bracket?

But I don't know at which place ?

*Pls Anyone knows then help me*

```
    @override 
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text("LogIn"),
    body: Column(
        children: [
      TextField(
      controller: _email,
        obscureText: false,
        enableSuggestions: false,
        autocorrect: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        decoration: const InputDecoration (
          hintText: 'Enter Your Email Here',
          ),
      ),
      TextField(
      controller: _password,
        obscureText: true,
        enableSuggestions: false,
        autocorrect: false,
        decoration: const InputDecoration (
          hintText: 'Enter Your Password Here',
          ),
      ),
      TextButton(
       onPressed: () async { 
       final email = _email.text;
        final password = _password.text;
      try { final userCredential =
             await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword (
           email: email,
           password: password,
       );
         print(userCredential);
         } on FirebaseAuthExceptions catch (e){
         If (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
         print("User is not Found");
        } Else if (e.code == 'wrong password') {
         print("Wrong Password");
         }
         }
         },
        child: Text("LogIn"),
        ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed:() {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/Register/',
                (route) => false,
            );
            },
            child: const Text("Not Register Yet? Register Here"),
            )
          ],
        )
          default:
            return const Text("Loading..."); 
      },
      }
        )
      )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please write a minimum executable source. Is it the `default` of `switch~case`?

Comment: Can you include more snippet

Comment: Yes i add more snippet

Comment: Hi Sumit. Please share your complete code. Looks like you are trying to write switch case but the code is not complete so we can predict only. Also that's not the way to write switch case. Can you please clarify a bit what you want to acheive?

Comment: Yes i added more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means `default` is on the wrong place... check the parentheses

**Update because of new code snippet:**

You shared not enough code... but if you have a switch case statement it should look like this:

```
Widget getWidget(String input) {
  switch (input) {
    case 'lala':
      return Container();
    case 'bibi':
      return TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            '/Register/',
            (route) => false,
          );
        },
        child: const Text("Not Register Yet? Register Here"),
      );
    default:
      return const Text("Loading...");
  }
}
```

please share your whole code for detailed help.

**2. Update**

Thank you for sharing. At this place a default value can't be set.
I checked your Widget for wrong parentheses and this should work for you:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("LogIn"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _email,
            obscureText: false,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: const InputDecoration (
              hintText: 'Enter Your Email Here',
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _password,
            obscureText: true,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration (
              hintText: 'Enter Your Password Here',
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final email = _email.text;
              final password = _password.text;
              try { final userCredential =
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword (
                email: email,
                password: password,
              );
              print(userCredential);
              } on FirebaseAuthExceptions catch (e){
                if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                  print("User is not Found");
                } Else if (e.code == 'wrong password') {
                  print("Wrong Password");
                }
              }
            },
            child: Text("LogIn"),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed:() {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                '/Register/',
                    (route) => false,
              );
            },
            child: const Text("Not Register Yet? Register Here"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Which braces ? I mean at which place

Comment: If I use `;` after the round bracket just above the default then it gives me an error "Expected to find ')'." That's why I am not using `;`.

Comment: I corrected it, but had to remove default, as there is no default parameter at this place. I think you want to show "loading" text during the communication with firebase, am I right? Then you should work with setState after awaiting firebase... maybe this helps: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/loading-error-states-state-notifier-async-value/

Comment: Thanks You Very Much For Your Support  . Now my code run successfully